# Notification sound stops playing after a while

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

I've implemented the below code to enable receiving push notifications and show it to user and play a sound alarm. It works fine. But according the some users feedback, it stops playing sound alarm, even though the notification is shown properly.

In the device settings / Notifications, it seems that the category is set to Silent automatically. But I don't know why!

```
    Uri soundUri1 = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://" + context.getPackageName() + "/" +R.raw.sound1);//

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                .build();
        channel.setSound(soundUri1, audioAttributes);
        NotificationManager manager = context.getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
    NotificationCompat.Builder buider = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
    buider.setContentTitle(title);
    buider.setContentText(messageBody);
    buider.setSound(soundUri1);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(context, MainActivity.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
    buider.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

    NotificationManagerCompat.from(context).notify(Tools.getNotificationId(context), buider.build());
```

Comment: Were you able to resolve it?

Comment: @RedSun unfortunately no